# How far can locust swarms expand and beplague?

Tags: migration

[March 2020](http://www.fao.org/ag/locusts/en/archives/1340/2517/2518/index.html) is the the latest map that I see. I'm asking about all relevant species of locusts. What's the maximum effective range for these locusts swarms? Southern Europe? China? Japan?

I read [Michel Locoq's answer on Dec 9 2013](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Can_an_insect_fly_1000_km_over_sea) but it doesn't answer for swarms.

> In 1988, locusts swarms travelled some 5000 km non-stop from West Africa to the Americas. Several waves of locusts arrived between 7 October and 4 November 1988. This was not at all a single event. There is other examples: migration of swarms from Africa to British Isles in 1954, migration half-way across the Atlantic in 1865 and 1916, etc.
>
> Desert locust can resist to starvation and cold temperatures. Just a few days without food is not too much for an insect living normally in desertic areas, migrating during months for food and humidity for its eggs. And they can survive quite well at low temperatures. I have seen swarms crossing the Atlas mountains in Morocco, they can settle in the snow and start again when the sun appears. No need for human help (and what kind of help for large swarms of bilion of insects ?) to cross the ocean. it's just a good flying insect. Its flying capacity is so developed that there is no genetic differences between mauritanian populations and populations from Pakistan.
> [image]